# Flutter how to automatic navigation from page to another

Tags: java, android, ios, flutter, dart

I'm writing a flutter application and i want to change the page without any users interaction when a condition is reached
iw ant the navigation to be when `a =2;`

```
  int a=0;

  HeadsetEvent headsetPlugin = new HeadsetEvent();
  HeadsetState headsetEvent;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    /// if headset is plugged
    headsetPlugin.getCurrentState.then((_val){
      setState(() {
        headsetEvent = _val;
        a=1;
      });
    });

    /// Detect the moment headset is plugged or unplugged
    headsetPlugin.setListener((_val) {
      setState(() {
        headsetEvent = _val;
        a=2;
      });
    });
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("auto navigation"),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Text(a.toString()),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

that's a code with a variable a a eaach time take a value i want the navigation when a=2 thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit :**

```
headsetPlugin.setListener((_val) {
  setState(() {
    headsetEvent = _val;
  });
Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute()),
      );
});
```

Comment: @MohamedBorheneDhahri post some code so i can help you.

Comment: thank you it works but i want another thing if we can test a widget state for exmeple the color of a container

Comment: @MohamedBorheneDhahri make a new organized post and detail how you approached the problem along with the code that didn't work for you, this is how stackoverflow works.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61854040/flutter-how-to-check-if-a-drawwiget-is-completetly-drawn i add a new question in this link